# How can I generate digital audio from software?

Tags: audio, coaxial, dolbydigital

I have a laptop (ASUS X540B) that is currently my only computer. I checked, it does not have an S/PDIF 3.5mm jack. The speakers I have are the original Xbox 5.1 by Spherex, kinda obscure but whatever. I tried the analog in (the 2 channel RCA jacks, you know) but the left channel doesn't work. I have confirmed it is not the cable, as I have swapped left and right and it is still the left input that is just silent.

On the back of the surround sound receiver there are two "Optical in" jacks, and one just labelled "coax". I figure that I should be able to just use the 3.5mm to RCA cable I already have, and just plug one of the cords into the "coax" jack, right?

The thing I'm missing is some kind of software to generate Dolby Digital signals (it doesn't even have to be 5.1) and output it from either the left or right channel. I don't want to buy anything, so please don't link anything unless it's under $3.

So my question is, are there any software or drivers out there that will let me do that? Or would I have to code something myself?

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop? Please [edit] the question to include this important information.

Comment: What do you mean by receiver? Please add that to the question as well.

Comment: Unless your computer already has digital out [which most don't] then the optical & coax inputs are no good to you at all. If you have mini-jacks on the computer, they are quite probably stereo jacks, so you need a 3.5mm stereo to twin RCA adaptor. That might just fit in your 3 buck budget too ;-) We do need the precise laptop spec to be certain, though, so this isn't an answer until we get it.

Comment: D'oh, missed it earlier - Asus spec says "1 x COMBO audio jack " so it's probably a 'headset' jack. You could see if someone makes one of those to RCA.

Answer (score 0):

As the laptop has what is probably a standard 'headset jack' 3.5mm TRRS, then you need an adaptor from that to RCA.

The digital connections are no use to you, unless you invest in a considerably more expensive USB output converter, which you said is outside your budget.

So, long & short - forget 5.1, accept stereo.

There's a rough guide to identifying plug types on [CableChick - Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/)